# Can you get duplicate character pieces in Plants vs Zombies Garden Warfare?

Tags: plants-vs-zombies-garden-warfare

I recently got PVZ Garden warfare for my Xbox 360. I was wondering if its possible to get duplicate character pieces, items, or skin customizations when opening booster packs?

I know some items are consumables so you will get multiples but I was wonder if its the same for the rarer items and if it was possible to trade them away if this happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to get duplicates, so once you've unlocked everything, you just get extra consumables in packs instead of non-consumables.

Comment: does this include Customization items as well?

Answer (score 0):

No it's not possible. Plus why would you need to duplicate them.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible. But maybe 1 in a billion users may receive a glitch. But don't worry. You wont get duplicate packs. FYI: I got it for Pc. So my answer may not be best for ya. But I'm sure its same for both counsels. Please rate me High if you thing I gave a good answer or a lower one for a poor answer. Thank you for letting me answering you Question.